# Creating Java jobs pool

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, concurrency, connection-pooling

My application JavaEE app is backend service of mobile clients so the clients must be registered to backend service, there are lots of database process and different kinds of jobs in the registration process, to improve performance I am plannig to create job pool, for example when client is registering to backend service their jobs pushed to pool until the pool size getting full. If the pull size is full, jobs will be processed... Is there any suitable way to implement this idea ?

thanks,

Comment: Why would you wait until the pool is full, I would just push the jobs into a JMS?

Comment: My main target is collecting jobs and excecute in one times,

Comment: Have a look if there is something like an Activiation Spec for your Application Server.

Comment: Also how would the pooling improve performance, by pooling the jobs you would create load peeks.

Answer (score 1):

What is the reason for waiting until you accumulate a big block instead of quickly processing small chunks? Performance-wise this is almost always better, not even speaking of transactions and such. Plus your clients wait longer than necessary.

If you really want to do it, I'd go for storing all incoming requests in a List, the database or a queue, whatever you prefer and whether it needs to be persistent, and have a periodical job checking for new ones and processing them, if needed only if a certain threshold exceeded.

Comment: Actually, I am trying to this to response quickly to clients, my aim is that, clients do not need to wait all jobs...

Comment: Then all you need to do is executing the actual job asynchronously, for example by using AsynchrousEJB or a JMS queue, and return immediately back to the client. This is a common technique for longer running requests. In case you need to inform the clients of the success of the job you can either poll from them (depending on the number of clients this might generate high load) or use something like WebSockets (if possible within your architecture).